# Remove text string from excel that is separated by * and /

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a column of cells that contain samples of the following

```
a1 = D11F2/J3C2/FENCE*25A/23A/21A/20A
a2 = d11f2/00A/123/d6f2
```

I want to remove any 3 digit codes "/00A" they are generally separated by a / but as in the case in A1 it is separated by a star "*25a"

This formula/macro would result in:

```
a1 = D11F2/J3C2/FENCE
a2 = d11f2/d6f2
```

thanks for all the help!

I tried using substitute formula but it only removed first or second string after divider

Comment: please show us your attempt and where you struggled so we can assist you.

Comment: You call it "three digit codes" but in your example there is a letter. What are valid separators? Just `'/'` and `'*'`? `' '` as well? You are obviously leaving `D11` etc. alone... And in the case of '*25a', what is the rule to remove the separator - do you leave the leading separator alone, or the trailing one?

Comment: the only valid separators is "/" a star or space should be removed. To get a bigger understanding these are for parking spots. the old parkin lot was the 3 digit codes the new one is the 4 digit codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following VBA function appears to do what I understand you are asking for:

```
Function stripThree(s As String)
' find any sequence of three "digits"
' that are separated by either ' ', '*', or '/'
' and remove them, including their leading separator

Dim ii, l, lastGood, lastSep As Integer
Dim retval As String

lastGood = 0
lastSep = 0

For ii = 1 To Len(s)
  l = Mid(s, ii, 1)
  retval = retval & l
  If l = "/" Or l = "*" Or l = " " Then
    If ii - lastSep = 4 Then
      retval = Left(retval, Len(retval) - 5) & l
    End If
    lastSep = ii
  End If
Next ii

' if last "separator" is the end of the string
' we still need to remove the three digit/letter code
If lastSep + 4 = ii Then
  retval = Left(retval, Len(retval) - 4)
End If


stripThree = retval

End Function
```

Examples of this code at work:

```
input:  D11F2/J3C2/FENCE*25A/23A/21A/20A
output: D11F2/J3C2/FENCE

input:  d11f2/00A/123/d6f2
output: d11f2/d6f2
```

as stipulated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide another solution without coding or formula. It will be easy for everybody to do it.

1. Selection the region of data. eg. A1:A20
2. Press “**Ctrl+H**" to call replace function.
3. lookup region to fill: **~** to find star, replaced by region:/
   Then you can replace all star() as slash(/)

   lookup:~*

   replace:/

   For spacer replace, use the same way, space just tpye " ". without", no need ~.

   lookup:  (<--there is a spacer)

   replace:/
4. Ctrl+H again.

   lookup: /???/

   Replace:/

Now you replaced all of the /3 digits except the suffix of /xxx
5. Use filter to select the code with suffix of /xxx

filter: */???

process it by separately. Maybe still need one formula: **= left(A1,len(A1)-4)**